# How to change font color from C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a simple Calendar application and I would like to change the color of names of the days that are displayed. I created a simple condition:

```
if (nameDay.Text.Equals("Sunday"))
{
    daytxt.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
```

But in this case the color is changing permanently. When the name of day changes to "Monday" then color of the text is still red but it should be black. How can I fix my issue?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An `else` condition is missing from your `if` statement in order to achieve what you need.

You can do it 1 of 2 ways:

```
if (nameDay.Text.Equals("Sunday"))
{
    daytxt.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}
else
{
    daytxt.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}
```

Or

```
daytxt.Foreground = nameDay.Text.Equals("Sunday") ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Black;
```

Comment: So it enough to add "else"... Thank you, it's working.

Comment: Why it should turn black again if you don't tell it somewhere?